# Multiple filters with AND and OR operator giving incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get list of employees based on following filters :

```
DepartmentId 
DivisionId
```

**Use case 1:** If user has selected only department as filter then ignore DivisionId and get employees only by DepartmentId

**Use case 2:** If user has selected both department and division as filter then get employees by both DepartmentId and DivisionId

**Use case 3:** If Department is not selected then get all employees(discard Department and Division filter)

Query:

```
DECLARE @departmentId AS int, @divisionId AS int
set @departmentId = 1
set @divisionId = 100
select * from Employees where 
(DepartmentId is null  or 
   (DepartmentId = @departmentId and 
      (DivisionId is null or DivisionId = @divisionId)))
```

Problem here is I am even getting the records where DepartmentId and DivisionId both are null whereas I just want 1 record whose `DepartmentId = 1 and DivisionId = 100`

Can someone please help me with fixing this logical issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want:

```
where (@DepartmentId is null or DepartmentId = @departmentId) and 
      (@DivisionId is null or DivisionId = @divisionId)
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me. If I am having couple of more additional filters before this department and division then Do I need to wrap this entire logic in bracket ?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow . . . That sounds right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
where (@departmentID is null) or
      (@divisionID is null and DepartmentID = @departmentID) or
      (DepartmentID = @departmentID and DivisionID = @divisionID)
```